# Boost header file linking error when I try to compile on Cygwin

Tags: c++

I'm getting the error:

```
In file included from sourcefile.cpp:35:0:
myrandom.h:10:45: fatal error: boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

when I try to compile my source file with:

```
g++ -o sourcefile sourcefile.cpp -I/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/Documents/Libraries/boost_1_55_0/ -L/cygdrive/c/Users/myname/Documents/Libraries/boost_1_55_0/libs/ -Wall -O0
```

I haven't had this problem before and everything was working fine. I'm not sure what's wrong and it's driving me nuts. Can you help me figure it out?

Comment: and does the file mersenne_twister.hpp exist in that location?

Comment: Yes, it exists in C:\Users\myname\Documents\Libraries\boost_1_55_0\boost\random

Comment: try putting the include path directive before the source file on the command line

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but I'm getting the same error.